# Https url data download issue with apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am facing a unique problem with apache camel https4 call. My case is something like below:

1. I have to make a post https request to a third party with authentication credentials(request identifiers) in body of request. - This works fine 
   Example url : **https4://< requesturl >?httpClientConfigurer=proxyClientConfigurer**
2. The successful response will give me a download url to request for files download. This url is returned in the format **https://< requesturl >?args=< file identifier >** which if i invoke through a browser, downloads all the files instantly.
3. However for invoking it through apache camel i have to use **https4** and need to append **httpClientConfigurer=proxyClientConfigurer** to download request url. So the final url is something like                                                                                         **https4://< requesturl >?args=< file identifier>&httpClientConfigurer=proxyClientConfigurer**        and this is the part its failing.

the server treat it as a new request and looks for the authentication/information which is not present and hence the call fails.
I don't know what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i didn't find a solution for this through Camel but i went ahead and used the normal Http Get with the download url.